# Reserve BufferOverflow.com

Tags: discussion, domain-names

[BufferOverflow.com](http://bufferoverflow.com/) is currently unregistered, and can be reserved. Possibly for "defensive registration", as Spudley suggests in the comment below. Until there's a use for it, it can be a redirect to StackOverflow.com.

Comment: @muntoo - I suggest you come up with a real reason soon... already picking up plenty of downvotes in a short time. Maybe an Area 51 Buffy site.

Comment: the most obvious reason would be as a defensive registration. But whether that's something the site owners would do or not is another question (when you start down that path, it can become a never-ending money-pit)

Comment: How is anyone going to think buffer and stack are spelt the same?

Comment: I would believe `NullReference.com` should be protected but not `bufferOverlow`

Comment: both are gone :-P

Comment: [It's not unregistered.](http://who.is/whois/bufferoverflow.com/)

Comment: So far your only argument for doing so is that it is unregistered. So what? Why does that matter?  Are you suggesting that people will try to use `bufferoverflow.com` to try to reach Stack Overflow (as @random suggests)? Or you think that some time in the future a sister site will be spawned with that name? Again, why would that happen? Only 3 sites will have their own TLD AFAIK: SO, SF and SU. Everything else will become a subdomain of `stackexchange.com`. I don't see any compelling reason why they'd want to reserve that name for anything (or any useful site would be named that).

Comment: @jeff Careful with *`or any useful site would be named that`*. Who would have thought someone would name a site "Stack Overflow"?

Comment: @Richard: Yes but Stack already covers all things to do with programming.  Any other conceivable usage that relates to that name would be too narrow to even become a live site or has a proposal on Area51 with a better name.  I'm not saying that it's impossible that the `bufferoverflow.com` domain will ever be used, it might be some time in the future, I'm just saying that there's no probable reason why SEI would want to reserve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see...

```
bufferunderrun.com
stackoverflows.com
stack-overflow.com (hyphenated!)
nullreferenceexception.com
nullpointerexception.com
outofstackspace.com
accessviolation.com
undefined.com
```

Why again do you think bufferoverflow is special??

---

99.9% of stackoverflow/stackexchange traffic doesn't come from manually typing the URL. And of the 0.1%, 99% of the people who will type it actually know the correct name, and no sane person will go to bufferoverflow.com for no reason expecting to find help on the other end.

Comment: It's not reserved.

Comment: And why reserve it when there already exists so many other sibling variants that have nothing to do with StackOverflow?

Comment: @Richard *A journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step.* - Confucius

Comment: @muntoo - answer edited

Comment: @muntoo Confucius say, *If you no understand difference between buffer overflow and stack overflow, you no come to Stack Overflow and ask silly questions.* Seriously, how is randomly quoting philosophers going to help your case here?